# How to separate the files from Google Drive in the Response only using Rest API

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-8-emulator

Hi I'M new to windows phone Application development i'm working on how to get access the files   from google drive using rest api i got the response in the response i got all the information like .pdf,.docs,mp3,mp4 ,folders etc...and the response is coming slow from the web for that is there any solution that.I should  get response only that contains images and folders so that app will fast and accuracy... Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I had got the response from that i'm seperating the images accoring to mimetype but it takes lot of time to deserilaize and to seperation is there any alternative solution for this

Comment: According to Mimetype in the querySearch result we can purify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q=mimeType contains 'image/jpeg'

The above link is for getting only images in this way according to mime type we can get the files rather than getting all files at a time